# Effects of Auslogic BoostSpeed on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have heard Auslogic BoostSpeed is really good with Windows XP.

Is it similarly good with Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auslogic BoostSpeed is an awesome program, i use it on all my computers almost every day and they are running with no problems (a couple of them are 5 years old now) all running Windows 7 Ultimate.